# Why is tan(x) denote a line perpendicular to the tangent, not the tangent itself?

Tags: trigonometry, tangent-line

I asked a question before, and was directed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447575/why-is-the-tangent-of-an-angle-called-that/3447586#3447586) instead. :^(  Hopefully, someone reading on this thread might still be able to help answer my question.

I am trying to understand how the word "tangent" was decided in trigonometric nomenclature, why did mathematicians choose the name of the exact opposite of the tangent line?  In geometry, the definition of Tangent is "a straight line or plane that touches a curve or curved surface at a point, but if extended does not cross it at that point".[Geometric definition of Tangent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXuPV.jpg)

BTW - In Doug M's response, he has 2 pics of unit circles.  (It is nice to have a visual to work with, by the way)  On the 1st one, he shows a red line and says the vertical line that intersects with the line radiating from the unit circle is "has a measure of  tanx".  I get what he is trying to get across with this statement.  That is the definition of x/y in a unit circle (1/1=1), but not in every quadrant.  Tanx of 135° is negative, there is a sign associated with that measure.  TanX is the slope of the line that contains the radius perpendicular to the circle.  The way I read Doug's statement seems to only be a true (between 0-90° and at exactly 180°).  Of course, I will clearly accept corrections to any wayward logic.

Comment: Maybe the picture here is more clear: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40364/what-reasoning-is-behind-the-names-of-the-trigonometric-functions-sine-secan

Comment: “[...] why did mathematicians choose the name of the exact opposite of the tangent line?” The tangent line to **what**, and at which point? It's not clear (to me at least) which line you are talking about.

Comment: I don't know enough here to respond individually so...

Mr. Heer: - In Doug's original answer (link is in my question), he shows a red, vertical line and calls it the tangent.  The point on the curve (for the sake of argument) is (π/4, π/4).  Tanx at that pt is 1.  The red line Doug declares as tangent is not tangent to that pt, it is tangent at (1,0).  Furthermore, that line's magnitude is not 1.

Mr. Hardy: Respectfully, that definition comes from https://www.lexico.com/definition/tangent  The blue line (in your picture) is a tangent to the circle only at (1,0), same as Doug's.

Answer (score 6):

> "a straight line or plane that touches a curve or curved surface at a point, but if extended does not cross it at that point"

That is wrong. The tangent line to the graph of $y = \sin x$ at $x=0$ crosses the graph at the point at which it is tangent to the graph.

The blue line in the picture is tangent to the circle.

The angle $\theta$ corresponds to a line passing through the center and crossing the circle at two points. The point where that line intersection the blue tangent line corresponds to a number, which is the tangent of the angle. **That is true in either the left or the right half of the circle and either above or below the horizontal axis.** At the top and bottom of the circle, you get a line not intersecting the blue tangent line. That can be considered to intersect it at $\infty,$ and that is neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty,$ but is the $\infty$ that is approached by going in either direction along the line.

[image]

Comment: +1.  The OP makes a good point, though, that this explanation only works for angles in the first quadrant.  How do you interpret $\tan 120^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$ geometrically?

Comment: @mweiss : You are mistaken. This works in all four quadrants, as I explained in this posting itself. Read carefully. $\qquad$

Comment: @mweiss same way you interpret $\cos 120^\circ=-1/2$. One has to look at the tangent line through $(-1,0)$, but I'm sure there's a way to make the definition "natural"

Comment: @ElliotG : You are also mistaken. You don't need more than that one blue tangent line. Again, read carefully.

Comment: @mweiss : My posted answer said "That is true in either the left or the right half of the circle" and you ignored that. So now I have expanded that sentence so that it says "That is true in either the left or the right half of the circle and either above or below the horizontal axis." and set it in bold. $\qquad$

Comment: Ah I see, emphasis on the intersection of the *line* through $(0,0)$ and $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ with the blue line. That is nice

Comment: I think the phrase I misunderstood was "The point where that line intersection the blue tangent line *corresponds to* a number [emphasis added]".  By "corresponds to a number" you just mean "Has a $y$-coordinate", right?

Comment: @mweiss Yes. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

It is true now that the tangent is now taught as the slope of a radius.

But that is not the historical understanding of things.

“Slope” is a concept from coordinate (aka Cartesian) geometry.

Trigonometric functions were studied long before coordinate geometry. All six functions were used by the 10th century, long before Descarte.

In Euclidean geometry, the key measures are angles and lengths. And several people here have already indicated a length of $\tan x$ that:

1. Is a length, of a line segment,
2. Which is a tangent to the circle,
3. And is directly related to the angle in question

Names in general have murky origins. Sometimes names make no sense at all. For an example from this answe: Why do we call coordinate geometry “Cartesian” when his name was Descarte.

But here, we have a perfectly fine reason for the name. It is the length of a tangent line segment.

Yes, the tangent function, as defined now, is signed, but we don’t know if the name came before or after that notion of a signed function, and the sign of a tangent can still be explained by giving a direction to the circle (counterclockwise, usually) and talk about the counterclockwise angle and “directional distance” of the circle tangent in the counterclockwise direction.

While that makes mathematical sense, that is probably ahistorical, too.

Comment: THANK YOU, Mr. Andrews!  That answers my question.  Since I learned Geometry as a Sophomore and pre-Calculus as a Senior, my assumption was exactly opposite of the correct chronology.